# How do I map dynamically created columns in SSRS 2008?

Tags: dynamic, reporting-services, names

I wrote a stored procedure, whose results include 4 columns whose names will change over time.
They correspond to Week numbers. So one column will be '1', another will be '2' and so on.
They will continue to change when the report runs, ie, '49','50','51','52'. In Report Builder you have to map column name to column name, but the column name will change, they are not static.

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: No offense intended, but this sounds a bit like an XY problem. Why do you have changing column names? (It sounds a little like you're trying to feed pre-formatted or perhaps pre-pivoted "data" into SSRS.)

Answer (score 0):

SSRS does not support dynamic column names.  I would recode your stored procedure to return a Week column with values 1, 2 etc.